# Visualization of iteration procedure in NMinimize

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization, visualization

I have this optimization code:

```
vars1 = Array[Subscript[x, #] &, {4}];
ka = {35, 10, 20, 25};
objectiveFunction = Total[ka.vars1^5];
NMinimize[{objectiveFunction/100, 
Apply[And, Thread[GreaterEqual[vars1, 0]]] && Total[vars1] == 100 &&
Element[vars1, Integers]}, Flatten[vars1], MaxIterations -> 200]
```

How is it possible in MMA to capture the values of variables and also objective function in each iteration and plot them versus iteration number??(Separate plots or all in one plot?)

Comment: [Have a look at the `EvaluationMonitor` examples](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EvaluationMonitor.html). There are also some examples in the `EvaluationMonitor` section of [`NMinimize` documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NMinimize.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
vars1 = Array[x, {4}];
ka = {35, 10, 20, 25};
objectiveFunction = ka.vars1^5;
s = {};
Dynamic@If[Length@s > 3, ListLinePlot[Transpose@s, PlotRange -> {{0, 200}, {0, 100}}, 
                                      GridLines -> {{Length@s}, {}}],,]
k[vars1_] := NMinimize[{objectiveFunction, And @@ Thread[GreaterEqual[vars1, 0]] &&  
                        Tr@vars1 == 100 && vars1 ∈ Integers},
                        vars1, MaxIterations -> 200, StepMonitor :> AppendTo[s, vars1]]
k[vars1]
```

[image]

Comment: Great belisarius!!! that is what I was looking for but is it also possible to have the monitoring plot during iterations at the same time??I mean exactly when we have the iteration data?Or it is different story?

Comment: @Alex See edit, please

Comment: one more thing why when I changing the separated variables that you put in `Sow[{x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4]}]]` to `Sow[vars1]` it is not returning the `x[1]` value but the rest?What if I have 100 variables?Can I do that same way?

Comment: Nice +1.  Just how I would do it.  Why is the vertical plot range going to 100, when the option sets the limit at 40?

Comment: Great dynamic modelling is really great!!!

Comment: @MichaelE2 Because I used a slightly different version for saving the images to disk

Comment: @Alex It was a scoping problem. Check the code now.

Comment: @belisarius you are great teacher!!!Thanks!